# Delete a windows service, and then re-install it using powershell

Tags: powershell, windows-services

How can I use powershell to delete a service, and then re-install it right afterwards?

What I'm trying right now:

- using sc.exe stop "servicename"
- after that i do sc.exe delete "servicename"

  - sometimes this actually returns an error saying service is marked for deletion
- after that I do get-service "servicename" again to see if the service is deleted

  - this doesn't work as it says the service still exists

As far as I know, all services windows are closed, server management, task manager, etc are all closed. However get-service consistently returns that a service exists even when it should be deleted.

Is there a magic way to completely delete / reinstall services in one script?

Comment: What is the service? Why do you think you need to uninstall it? How did it get installed in the first place?

Comment: Agree - what problem are you actually trying to solve? (Describe the problem, not your attempted solution.)

Comment: Unless you're changing service settings, removing and re-adding a service isn't going to do anything more than stopping and starting it. We certainly need more info on what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: This is a windows service that I am developing. Someone else on the team believes that we need to completely uninstall / reinstall a service every time we deploy a new build (using TFS). We are having issues with this script though because of the service not deleting itself correctly, or just being marked for deletion

Comment: "Someone else on the team believes that we need to completely uninstall / reinstall a service every time we deploy a new build (using TFS)" - IMO this someone needs to provide a justification. If the service name and executable path don't change, there should be no need to delete and reinstall.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart I'm curious what would be the best strategy for having continuous deployment of a windows service? I also thought it would be better to reinstall the service in case the path to the executable changed. In my case it's highly unlikely that we would change the path but not catering for the path possibly changing seems a bit too rigid whereas it could be catered for with a reinstall

Answer (score 3):

There are a few things you need to consider:

- `sc.exe stop <Service>` doesn't actually wait until the service is stopped. But fortunately `Stop-Service` exists in PS 5.1 and this does wait
- Same with `sc.exe delete <Service>`, this doesn't wait either, it simply marks it for deletion and returns. Also, in PS 5.1 we don't have a `Remove-Service` yet (which to my knowledge isn't waiting as well, so it doesn't matter)

I decided to just perform a loop checking until it's gone. So my approach has been this:

```
$service = Get-Service -Name 'My Service'
$service | Stop-Service

sc.exe delete 'My Service'

$maximumWaitTime = [TimeSpan]::FromSeconds(60)
$timer = [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()
do {
    $service = $null
    $service = Get-Service -Name 'My Service' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1

    if ($timer.Elapsed -gt $maximumWaitTime) {
        throw "Timeout while waiting for service 'My Service' to be removed"
    }
} while ($service -ne $null)
$timer.Stop()
Write-Output "Waited $($timer.Elapsed) until service was removed."

# And now I can delete service files, install new service, etc..
```

As you can see this code also has a timeout, if by any chance the service never ends up getting removed, although I have not seen this happen yet.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Alternatively you could use && to only run new-service if the first cmdlet succeeds.

```
  Remove-Service $service; New Service $service
```

Comment: Unfortunately we use powershell v4 and remove-service is not available

Comment: Remove-Service is available in Powershell 6 and up

Answer (score 0):

The script we were using was potentially adding a handle to the service, which means that it wouldn't delete until the script was done running. I split the additional check to see if the service actually was deleted into another Powershell process and it seems to delete correctly now...